# Smalltalk - Seaside, Magritte: "object description" giving "MessageNotUnderstood" exception

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I am working through the Seaside Book (http://book.seaside.st/). I am currently busy with the chapter on Magritte.

I followed the steps of the first example (http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/magritte/first-examples) but when I try to inspect the object's description, I get the MessageNotUnderstood: Address >> descriptionStreet.

```
|address|
address := Address example1.
address description.
```

If I understand this correctly:

> Note that there is no need to have a one to one mapping between the
>   instance variables of the class and the associated descriptions.
>
> All descriptions are automatically collected and put into a container
>   description when sending description to the object

there is no need for a "description" selector in my Address class? Why am I getting the error?

Comment: The text reads: "We define a class Address with four instance variables and their corresponding accessors." Have you created the accessors in the instance side of `Address`? Most likely you don't have done that yet and that's why you get the MNU exception.

Comment: Yes, I have created the accessors.

Comment: Then please copy (from the debugger) and paste in your question the list of messages that end up sending `descriptionStreet`.

Comment: Sorry - not sure if I understand you correctly, but it does not seem as if any message send descriptionStreet...

Comment: When using a pragma <magritteDescription> you cannot see the visitors that send it. take a look at MAPragmaBuilder to see how that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Seaside Book is outdated.

In Magritte3 you do not use "description" but "magritteDescription".

If you are following the book you will also run into issues later with the Form not rendering. In Magritte3 you have to add the  pragma to the description method and description methods should be on the instance side and not the class side as indicated in the book.

See this link: http://www.slideshare.net/nickager/magritte3

Answer (score 1):

A modern magritte description for street might look like this

```
Address>>descriptionStreet
    <magritteDescription>
    ^ MAStringDescription new
        accessor: #street;
        label: 'Street';
        priority: 250;
        yourself
```